# Displaying .ai files in Java

Tags: java, image

I've been talking with an artist and she is planning to send me .ai files for a project I'm working on that is using Java for its front end. Unfortunately, I'm having a lot of trouble searching for this issue because search engines are replacing .ai with "a" (even when I specifically say not to) or are searching for artificial intelligence. Obviously neither of those are what I'm looking for.

Is anyone aware of a Java library capable of rendering .ai files as static images?

Comment: http://filext.com/file-extension/AI says Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.ai file are vector graphics, they shouldn't be used in production. When the final copy of your image is ready your artist should be sending you a .png / .jpg  or similar end working file.

.ai stands for Adobe Illustrator and are intended for use only by Illustrator. It's like a developer creating .java files and sending them to a client, it's more likely they'd want a executable jar or a program installer.

Worst case scenario you should install CS5.5 (there's a trial version) and exporting the .ai files to a static file type yourself.

Comment: Point taken for Java. Thanks! She had also said that flash has no problem displaying them. Are you indicating that using that they are also not to be used in production for Flash either?

Comment: Flash is part of the Adobe Creative Suite, the tools are meant to be used together, Flash, Photoshop, Illustrator, After Effects are almost all inter-operable.

Comment: I would disagree that no one should use ai files. It is a vector file format - this is often preferred to a bitmap. Not that there isn't a better format out there but why shouldn't we be able to work with a common file format?